# ReSharper (or something like it) for SQL Server / T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, resharper

Are there any IDEs or extensions to IDEs that allow editing stored procedures as if they were programs so that if I were to place my cursor on a call to a stored procedure when editing a stored procedure, I could hit F12 and it would load the stored procedure under the cursor into the IDE?

Being able to refactor out a block of code into a new stored procedure would also be a welcome improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) has a lot of useful features.  I'm not sure if it will do exactly what Refactor does, but worth a shot.

Comment: I like that a lot. Not really what I'm after (doesn't open the highlighted sproc) but it does have a lot of great features so I've upvoted it.

Comment: Neil!! Wow - what a small world! Isn't SO just fabulous. :)

Answer (score 7):

The [redgate toolbelt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/) has a nice range of features.

Comment: especially SQL Prompt 5.0, which now includes SQL Refactor, too! http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/

Comment: SQL Prompt 5 specifically includes the F12 feature you are asking for. This creates an ALTER statement. You can hover over the object and click on the tooltip to get the CREATE statement.

Comment: A very nice bundle indeed. Also very expensive.